# On price tags/labels why some nouns are used singular/plural regardless of countability?

Tags: terminology, morphology, cross-linguistic, semantics, research

Is there any explanation regarding why some nouns are used in singular form while the others are used in plural form such as price tags in stores or menus in restaurants. I know that in languages where there is count/mass distinction uncountable nouns such as milk, meat etc. are tagged in singular form. For example in Swedish, at the stores many countable items are naturally tagged in plural form such as "apelsiner(oranges)"and "jackor(jackets)" as they are tagged in English. However I noticed out that countable products such as cucumbers and onions are tagged in singular form as "gurka" and "lök" rather than "gurkor" and "lökar" on the contrary to other fruits and vegetables. Is there any examination/explanation in linguistics directly referring such terminology?

Comment: English grammar does not extend to price tags. Everybody makes up their own ways to print them.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, for example we see the tag "apples" not "apple" at supermarkets or restaurant menus. In English it is said as "I like apples" or "I buy apples" by using plurals. Isn't it related with that usage and grammatical formation?

Comment: Sometimes. By some people. Others follow their own rules and customs. It's their tags for their stuff and they can do it in whatever way seems best to them. No doubt some ways are better than others, but it's hard to tell which.

Comment: English grammar does extend to price tags and in fact a similar thing is known in English specifically in the garment industry, including price tags on clothing where singular forms such as "pant", "short", and "trouser" occur frequently, very unlike in common speech.

Comment: @jlawler, "they can do it in whatever way seems best to them". How is that different from pretty much all use of language?

Comment: Well, it's in print, for starts. Almost all use of language is in speech. And it's not intended to convey sentences and propositions; it's just a merchant labelling their wares. So it's not really language; it's more like decoration and advertising.

Comment: I would say a label is quite different from a price tag. A label might just be a logo or appeal to some style etc rather than being linguistic. A price tag has to communicate a minimum of information to potential purchasers to be of any utility.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. @hippietrail Your examples regarding garments sound at least compatible with some logic. Since garments are purchased by number not by kilos/mass I can bring an explanation to it on the contrary to the Swedish examples I have seen. I agree with you for the label/tag distinction, however I used them interchangeably.

Comment: @jlawler Yes but tags/labels are part of linguistic landscapes eventually and I just wondered why their singularity/plurality differ and why there are some exceptions. So what interests me is bare use of nominals on tags.

Comment: It's basically a good question. I wonder if there is any answer or just some guesses. I've never heard an explanation for the English garment case that didn't seem like just somebody's hunch. I would love to find that somebody once did a proper study on it.

Comment: It's pretty surprising that there isn't any material about that singularity/plurality tagging issues on the web. This message thread may be kind of precedent.I have only found "grocer's apostrophe" case which is an obvious typo made widely. Regarding garment examples given above I also think that they are typos. "Pants", "shorts" and "trousers" already possess plurality. So it's different than using "jacket" instead of "jackets". Examples from other languages will be appreciated as well.